# I badly wrote my ruby condition

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I do not understand why the conditions do not work, 
I would like the part to be executed, if the username and the password are null

```
post '/login' do

  credentials = CGI.parse request.body.read

  if credentials['username'].nil? || credentials['password'].nil?
    status 603
    return ;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong logic operator, OR(`||`) instead of AND (`&&`)

```
post '/login' do

  credentials = CGI.parse request.body.read

  if missing_credentials?
    status 603
    return ;
  end
end

private

def missing_credentials?
  credentials['username'].nil? && credentials['password'].nil?
end
```

Comment: It isn't any more OOP, though :)

Comment: haha fair enough, that was the closest term I could think of @SergioTulentsev,

Answer (score 1):

Your question indicates you want the code to be executed if the username AND password are nil. Your code will execute if the username OR password are nil.

But it makes more sense that you would want your code to execute if either part were missing. Assuming that's what you want, I would write the conditional as:

```
unless credentials['username'] && credentials['password']
```

If you really do want to execute the code only if both pieces are missing, then you can do:

```
unless credentials['username'] || credentials['password']
```